# Fill or reduce list intermediate values in python

Tags: python, list

i have a lot of lists with sequence coordinates but with different length. i need to create function to preprocess this list and return a list with length 30 filled with intermediate values or reduced(and recalculated).

For example, for 10 length output(fill):

```
input = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 8, 5, 4] # length = 8
output = [1, 2.3, 3, 5, 7, 9, 8, 6.3, 5, 4] # length = 10
```

for 10 length output(reduce):

```
input = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8, 6, 5, 4] # length = 12
output = [1, 2.5, 3.9, 5, 6.5, 7.9, 8.8, 6.5, 5, 4] # length = 10
```

Comment: It what sense it `2.3` an intermediate value between `1` and `3`? And why do you add the value between `1` + `3` and `8` + `5` but not some other pairs instead?

Comment: maybe it's bad example, it can be another value instead ```2.3```, i just need take list, add or reduce values for specific length and save distribution

Comment: @seblful So they're just random numbers placed at random offsets just to make the list a certain size. Is that it?

Comment: no, it's like take this values, create plot from them and then take specific numbers of values from this plot that can show all distribution on this plot (from start to the end)

Comment: What measures are you using to characterize the distribution (mean+stdev)? If the question is how to inject numbers into the sequence that won't change the distribution, that is interesting. You may want to look at imputation methods: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imputation_(statistics)

Answer (score 0):

i wanted to do something like this, sorry for bad explanation

```
def normalize_length_of_sequence(sequence, sequence_length=30):
    if len(sequence) < sequence_length:
        while len(sequence) != sequence_length:
            diff_in_seq_ind = np.diff(sequence).argmax()
            new_mean_walue = (sequence[diff_in_seq_ind] + sequence[diff_in_seq_ind+1]) / 2
            sequence.insert(diff_in_seq_ind + 1, new_mean_walue)
    elif len(sequence) > sequence_length:
            while len(sequence) != sequence_length:
                diff_in_seq_ind = np.abs(np.diff(sequence)).argmin()
                sequence.pop(diff_in_seq_ind)
    return sequence
```

Comment: This is not an answer. This should be in your question